# VS Code can't resolve app path in newly created Angular files

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

So, this is a weird one.
All of a sudden, VSCode can't resolve imports from app root paths in newly created files on my project.
If I add imports in an old file it works just fine, if I create a new file in another project it works as well, but here it can't, only relative paths work.
Compilation works just fine.

> Cannot find module 'app/...' or its corresponding type
> declarations.ts(2307)

I am working on a remote server using VSCode's Remote SSH extension.

Edit : It seems that for those files, VSCode is not able to read the tsconfig.base.json. If i copy the content front this file into tsconfig.json it works fine.

New files are created as not part on the project and do not read the tsconfig.app.json file.

Comment: Have you tried restarting `vscode`

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: Could it possible be a corrupted temp folder?

Comment: It might, how can i try fixing it?